# Continuity of a transformation between normed spaces

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

With the below, I'm a bit stuck as to where to proceed.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

**Proposition**: If $x_{n} \rightarrow x_{0}$ implies $f(x_{n}) \rightarrow f(x_{0})$ then the transformation $f$ mapping $X$ to $Y$ is continuous at $x_{0} \in X$.

**What I have so far**:

If $x_{n} \rightarrow x_{0}$ implies $f(x_{n}) \rightarrow f(x_{0})$, then for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $||f(x_{n}) - f(x_{0})|| < \epsilon$ for all points $x_{n} \in X$ for which $0 < ||x_{n} - x_{0}|| < \delta$.

The above looks like Rudin's definition for a limit.  But given I've seen the above also used as the definition for continuity of $f$ at $x_{0} \in X$, is there anything else that needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not special to normed linear spaces. It is true in any metric space.  Secondly, the definition of continuity  says for any $\epsilon >0$ there exist $\delta >0$ such that  $\|f(x)-f(x_0)\| <\epsilon$ whenever $\|x-x_0\| <\delta$. This does not refer to any sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $x_0$.

To prove this result you have to prove by contradiction. All you have to do is write down the meaning if $f$ being not continuous at $x_0$. Can you do that?

Comment: Understood regarding metric spaces!  Since I've been working in normed linear space I thought it best to avoid straying outside of this segment; did not mean to imply this is untrue elsewhere.  If I understand your point regarding contradiction, you're saying the optimal approach is with something like "assume to the contrary that $x_{n} \rightarrow x_{0}$ implies $f(x_{n}) \rightarrow f(x_{0})$ and $f$ is not continuous"?  And yes, my mistake regarding the definition of continuity!  I missed the lack of a subscript.